# Scala and Play framework 2.2.0, Action.async and isAuthenticated

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework-2.0

I have an app using the isAuthenticated pattern described in the zentasks example.
It's also using Future/Async to minimize blocking...

```
  def index = isAuthenticated { username => implicit request =>        
    val promise = 
      Future {
        Foo.all()    
      }
    Async {
      promise.map(f => Ok(views.html.foo.index(username, f)))
    }        
  }
```

This continues to work in Play 2.2.0 but the Future/Async pattern is deprecated.  We're supposed to use Action.async; something like:

```
  def asyncTest = Action.async {
    val fut = Future {
      // Artificial delay to test.
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      "McFly"
    }
    fut.map (f => Ok(f))      
  }
```

My question is; how would I use Action.async with the authentication method above, or something similar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option would be to use [Action Composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaActionsComposition) by defining `IsAuthenticated` like so:

```
def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("email")

def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Application.login)

def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Future[SimpleResult]) = {
  Action.async { request =>
    username(request).map { login =>
      f(login)(request)        
    }.getOrElse(Future.successful(onUnauthorized(request)))
  }
}
```

And then you could use it in the following way:

```
def index = IsAuthenticated { user => implicit request =>
  val fut = Future {
    // Artificial delay to test.
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    "McFly"
  }
  fut.map (f => Ok(f))      
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly and gives me insight into how this stuff actually works.  Thanks!